# Python function takes previous value even though new one is given through input

Tags: python

I am working on a library management system project, where there are two text files "books.txt" and "borrowers.txt". Every time someone borrows a book, the quantity of book is decreased by one in "books.txt"

This is my books.txt file:

```
1,Harry Potter,JK Rowling,30,$2,11
2,Start With Why,Simon Sinek,8,$1.5,8
3,Programming With Python,John Smith,20,$1.5,8
```

The first column consists of course ID and the last one is the quantity.

This is the function(stored in a separate file: "change") which replaces the quantity string.

```
def inplace_change(filename, old_string, new_string):
    # Safely read the input filename using 'with'
    with open(filename) as f:
        s = f.read()
        if old_string not in s:
            print('"{old_string}" not found in {filename}.'.format(**locals()))
            return

    # Safely write the changed content, if found in the file
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        print('Changing "{old_string}" to "{new_string}" in {filename}'.format(**locals()))
        s = s.replace(old_string, new_string)
        f.write(s)
```

and this is the function which lets users actually borrow the file from the library:

```
import change

with open('books.txt') as textFile:
    list1 = [line.strip().split(',') for line in textFile]
    print(list1)

dict = {}
    
def main_borrow():                   
    borrowerName = input("Enter your name: ").lower()
    bookID = input("Enter the required book ID: ")
    bookIDFound = False
    for i in range(len(list1)):
                for j in range(5):
                    if bookID == list1[i][0]:
                        bookIDFound = True
                        requestedBookID = bookID
                        print("The requested book is", list1[i])
                        dict1 = {borrowerName : list1[i][1]}
                        dString = repr(dict1)
                        f = open('borrowers.txt', 'a')
                        f.write(dString + '\n')
                        f.close()
                        nowAvailable = int(list1[i][5]) - 1
                        nowAvailableStr = str(nowAvailable)
                        print(nowAvailable)

                        change.inplace_change('books.txt', list1[i][5], nowAvailableStr)
                        
                        f.close()
                    break
    if bookIDFound == False:
        print("Enter a valid book ID: ")
```

This is the main file:

```
import borrow
print("Welcome to library management system\n")



def borrow1():
    print("\nYou wil now borrow a book\n")
    borrow.main_borrow()

def return1():
    print("\nYou will now return a book\n")

def exit():
    print("\nThank you for using our Library Management System\n")

while True:
    a = int(input("Enter '1' to borrow a book \nEnter '2' to return a book \nEnter '3' to exit \nPlease enter a value: "))
    if a == 1:
        borrow1()
    elif a == 2:
        return1()
    else:
        exit()
        break
```

Now the problem I am facing is, the program works fine, the first time i borrow a book, when i borrow it the second time under a different name, it says it cant find the string like this:

```
Enter '1' to borrow a book 
Enter '2' to return a book 
Enter '3' to exit 
Please enter a value: 1

You wil now borrow a book

Enter your name: Rojin Dumre
Enter the required book ID: 1
The requested book is ['1', 'Harry Potter', 'JK Rowling', '30', '$2', '10']
9
Changing "10" to "9" in books.txt
Enter '1' to borrow a book 
Enter '2' to return a book 
Enter '3' to exit 
Please enter a value: 1

You wil now borrow a book

Enter your name: Jetsun Drolma
Enter the required book ID: 1
The requested book is ['1', 'Harry Potter', 'JK Rowling', '30', '$2', '10']
9
"10" not found in books.txt.
Enter '1' to borrow a book 
Enter '2' to return a book 
Enter '3' to exit 
Please enter a value:
```

I have been trying for some 2 hours now, I cant figure it out. Also, please suggest me a better way to replace the string because if two books have the same quantity in books.txt file, the function replaces both quantities. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You've asked a decent question, however, one of the guidelines of stack overflow is to not post images of text. Copy/paste the output of your text into your post, and you're more likely to get help.

Comment: Oh!. I removed the image and copy pasted the output, thanks!

Comment: "# Safely write the changed content, if found in the file". No, it doesn't. The file is truncated immediately upon opening it for writing. If there is any error in the process of writing the previously read data back to the file, you've lost the original.

Comment: Python has a `csv` module for dealing with CSV files.`s.replace` is almost certainly not sufficient for ensuring you change the field you want to change, and *only* that field.

Comment: oh right!, but the thing is I am doing this project for college coursework and it does not need to be that complicated and I need to avoid importing external modules as much as possible. I actually solved the problem by moving the file reading code inside def main_borrow(): function. Another problem I am facing is that the inplace_change function changes all quantities if they have the same number of books available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are reading the file only once.
After updating the contents of the file, you need to read it again to get the latest contents.

You can do so by moving the file reading code to `main_borrow()`

```py
def main_borrow():
    with open('books.txt') as textFile:
        list1 = [line.strip().split(',') for line in textFile]
        print(list1)
```

As for changing the quantity only for the borrowed book, use the built-in `fileinput` module.

```py
import fileinput


def inplace_change(filename, book_id, old_string, new_string):
    for line in fileinput.input(files=filename, inplace=True):
        list = line.strip().split(',')
        if list[0] == book_id:
            list[5] = new_string
        print(','.join(list))

    fileinput.close()
```

And change call to `inplace_change` -

```py
inplace_change('books.txt', list1[i][0], list1[i][5], nowAvailableStr)
```

Here's a refactored version of `main_borrow` -

```py
def main_borrow():
    with open('books.txt') as textFile:
        lines = textFile.readlines()

    borrowerName = input("Enter your name: ").lower()
    bookID = input("Enter the required book ID: ")
    bookIDFound = False
    for line in lines:
        list = line.strip().split(',')
        if bookID == line[0]:
            bookIDFound = True
            requestedBookID = bookID
            print("The requested book is", list)
            dict1 = {borrowerName: list[1]}
            dString = repr(dict1)
            f = open('borrowers.txt', 'a')
            f.write(dString + '\n')
            f.close()
            nowAvailable = int(list[5]) - 1
            nowAvailableStr = str(nowAvailable)
            inplace_change('books.txt', list[0], list[5], nowAvailableStr)

            f.close()
            break

    if bookIDFound == False:
        print("Enter a valid book ID: ")
```

Comment: wow yeah, did not realize it was that easy. do you have any idea about the second problem? because if two books have the same quantity the function replaces both quantities.

Comment: Thats cuz you are reading the whole file and replacing all occurences of `old_string`  in `inplace_change`

Comment: yeah, but how can i replace only specific occurrence? I need to do this without importing external modules.

Comment: nicely done!, thank you very much. could you give an idea on how to go about things if I wanted to lets say, add the total amount of money a user needs to pay for the borrowed books? I know I need to first modify the main program so I can keep looping the borrow part for a specific user. I will do that. I just want an overview.

Comment: Save user name and book_id in borrowers.txt. Then read this file line by line and find lines where user name has the desired value, then read book_id from this line and store it in a list say books_borrowed. Now loop through books_borrowed and read book.txt line by line and if book_id is same read the amount from that line.